# Python - Executar o proximo comando sem esperar o término do primeiro

Tags: python

Boa noite pessoal.

Tenho a seguinte função para criar uma progress bar:

```
def progress_bar(p_value, p_max: int):
    """
    :70 = É o tamanho da barra
    :param p_value: Valor que está sendo iterado de um laço de repetição
    :param p_max: É a quantidade total do dados que está sendo iterado
    :return:
    """
    chars = int(p_value * 40 / float(p_max))
    percent = int((p_value / float(p_max)) * 100)
    sys.stdout.write("  ") + sys.stdout.write("#" * chars)
    sys.stdout.write(" " * (40 - chars + 2))
    if p_value >= p_max:
        sys.stdout.write("done. \n\n")
    else:
        sys.stdout.write("[%3i%%]\r" % percent)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Agora preciso chamar ela dentro do laço for abaixo para que a barra fique dentro do quadro criado pelo print superior e inferior.
O print superior tudo bem, cria de boa, mas o de baixo só cria depois que terminar o laço for.

Como faço para ele criar tudo junto e carregar a progress bar dentro do quadrado?

é mais por questão de estética mesmo.

```
print(" ╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗")
for i, item in enumerate(p_list):
    progress_bar(i + 1, len(p_list))
    print(" ║ " + item.ljust(75) + "║")
print(" ╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝")
```

Grato pelo apoio.

Comment: Qual um valor usual de p_list?

Comment: O p_list do progress_bar é um número inteiro recebido pelo len(), que nesse caso vem de uma lista.

Comment: Acho que não entendi muito bem sua dúvida... você quer que '########################################  done.' apareça após o último print?

Comment: Não. Preciso que crie o quadro, ou seja o primeiro print e o ultimo print e continue executando a progress_bar aparecendo gradativamente, normalmente os ########

Comment: 'normalmente os ######'....? Se você fizer if p_value > p_max o retângulo é criado normalmente (mas sem os ####). Do jeito que está ''######################################## done.' aparece antes dos dois últimos prints (último item da lista e parte inferior do retângulo). Você pode ser um pouco mais específico?

Comment: Não sei como ser mais específico que isso.
Estou só tentando deixar a progress_bar melhor de aparência.
Para não aparecer as # sozinhas no vácuo, entende. Fazer elas aparecerem dentro de um quadrado.

Comment: Acho que entendi.

Comment: Que bom. Estou ansioso..
Ainda estou tentando algo aqui também.

Comment: Acho que entendi o problema, mas não conheço muito bem a biblioteca sys e meu script teste está apresentando um comportamento estranho (ele só entre no else se eu colocar um print ali dentro...). De qualquer forma, você já tentou mexer na linha que escreve os ###? Algo como sys.stdout.write(" ") + sys.stdout.write("║ " + ("#" * chars) + "".ljust(75 - chars) + "║")

Comment: Vou testar essa sugestão.

Comment: Encontrei algo parecido no stack inglês mas é muito para meu tico e teco e não consegui aplicar.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21239032/print-2-lines-in-the-console-concurrently-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Nota 1**: Vou partir do princípio que o seu terminal suporta ANSI.
>
> **Nota 2**: Por uma questão de simplicidade, não vou abordar threads nessa resposta.

A função `print` do Python (e da maioria das linguagens de programação) recebe um texto e o escreve no terminal da esquerda pra direita, de cima para baixo (ou seja, de forma sequencial). No caso da sua barra de progresso, você precisa alterar este comportamento, de modo que você possa informar manualmente a posição de cada caractere.

Antes de mais nada, vamos criar uma função que limpa a tela do terminal. Você não disse qual sistema operacional está usando, então segue uma função portável (Windows e Unix):

```py
def limpar_tela():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
```

Agora vamos à função mais importante: Um `print` que recebe a linha e a coluna.

```py
def print_at(x, y, texto):
    print(f'\033[{y};{x}H{texto}')
```

Exemplo: A chamada `print_at(1, 1, 'G')` vai escrever um `G` na primeira linha e primeira coluna do seu terminal (isto é, o canto superior esquerdo).

Agora um simples laço `for` permite criar a barra de progresso. Podemos usar a função `time.sleep` para simular uma pequena espera a fim de visualizar a barra de progresso enchendo.

```py
limpar_tela()

print(" ╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗")
print(" ║                                                                                                    ║")
print(" ╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝")
print()
print(" Progresso: ")

for x in range(100):
    print_at(x + 3, 2, 'X')
    print_at(13, 5, f'{x + 1}%')
    time.sleep(0.03)

print()
```

Segue o código completo:

```py
import os
import time

def limpar_tela():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

def print_at(x, y, texto):
    print(f'\033[{y};{x}H{texto}')

def main():
    limpar_tela()

    print(" ╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗")
    print(" ║                                                                                                    ║")
    print(" ╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝")
    print()
    print(" Progresso: ")

    for x in range(100):
        print_at(x + 3, 2, 'X')
        print_at(13, 5, f'{x + 1}%')
        time.sleep(0.03)

    print()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Leitura adicional:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.name
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep
- http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm

Comment: Nossa, isso é incrível, Executei aqui e é isso que estou querendo. Agradeço profundamente.
Se não for abusar da sua bondade em ajudar. Esses processos muito pythonicos, digamos assim, é pouco complicado para minha cabeça entender e não manjo suficiente de inglês a ponto de ler profundamente a documentação, alguma coisa até entendo.
Preciso de ajuda para preencher a linha do meio:

Comment: print(" ╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗")
    print(" ║")
    print(" ╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝")
A linha do meio, o início eu coloquei, mas o final para aparecer fechado assim no início não consegui.

Se puder esclarecer melhor a linha:
def print_at(x, y, texto):
    print(f'\033[{y};{x}H{texto}')

Não entendi o que é o \033[{y};{x}H{texto};

Comment: Tentando ler melhor a documentação do link:
http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm

Acredito que entendi: será que confere:?
o "\33" é o código ANSI para <ESC>
O '[{y}' indica que irá começar naopsição determinada dos prints
O "{x}H{texto}" indica que irá começar no inicio da da segunda linha.

Agora não entendi essa linha:
print_at(105, 2, f'{x + 1}%')
E como colocar a barra vertical para iniciar fechado o print na segunda linha.

Comment: @CleberNandi A instrução `print_at(105, 2, f'{x + 1}%')` escreve a porcentagem da barra de progresso. O primeiro parâmetro é a coluna, o segundo é a linha, o terceiro é o texto. Ou seja, Vai escrever a porcentagem na coluna 105 da segunda linha.